# Add summary/teaser to Full content in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I want to have both Summary and Body in full content view in Drupal 7 but I can't understand how it is possible.

Comment: For what content type you want to do this? Basic page, article , custom content type?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit theme template files to do that. just edit node.tpl.php or page.tpl.php in your theme.

For example get summary in node.tpl.php:

```
// Load node summary view
$node_view = node_view($node,'summary');

// Get the summary
$summary = $node_view['body'][0]['#markup'];
```

Or use views to create the content you want.